# IIS is not serving a complete HTML response

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

I am deploying an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC app to a DEV server running IIS10. Two very complex Views share partial views. When I navigate to either, the HTML response is truncated. it appears to be capped at ~49kB transferred for the larger of the two, but the app serves other, less lengthy pages completely.

This obviously does not happen while debugging on IIS Express, but it does happen when I deploy to a local IIS instance as well as to another Test server where I have successfully run and tested another app with the same toolset.

I found one similar post for which the solution was to enable compression. This did not help. It served compressed, truncated responses.

Comment: I can't think of any causes off-hand, but you can find out by using IIS's **Request Tracing** and look at the dumped trace XML files. Share them with us by adding them to your post here if you have any questions or aren't able to find out from those traces.

Comment: ...though my _guess_ is there's an exception being thrown from within your `.cshtml`'s render functions and is being swallowed by a `try/catch` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, @Dai I've enabled trace logging, but the XML file for a truncated response contains ~100 Event segments. I'm looking for something "interesting" but it feels like a search for a needle in a haystack. The truncated page is served with an HTTP200. I also just noticed that it's size is 32768 characters. That can't be a coincidence. There has to be a response size setting somewhere!

Comment: Edit: the size was 32k once. It is usually 48k (19152) characters.

Comment: If you're having trouble with the trace, can you post it here so we can take a look? (I'm personally curious because I could swear the same thing happened to me as a one-off a couple of years ago)

Comment: @Dai - I am hesitant to post the entire trace because I don't know what's in the ~4k likes of XML that might reveal something about my infrastructure that shouldn't be on the interwebs. Can you point me to something that might point me in the direction of which sections might be of interest?

Comment: You could record a trace from an entirely different website that works fine, then do a `diff` between them, that should cut down on irrelevant noise.

Comment: I compared traces to a legacy site that runs under .NET 4.8. Both create the HTML in chunks and log the event in an event with the "GENERAL_RESPONSE_ENTITY_BUFFER" name. The .NET7 is using a buffer size of 4000, whereas the legacy app is using 8000. There are 4096 characters in each buffer chunk in the .NET7 log. Chrome is truncating the chunks in the other log - I assume they are 8192 characters. Both are using 64 bit threadpools. The output Caching setup for both apps is identical. I don't know that this is even part of the problem. I just noted it as a key difference.

Comment: There is one pair of GENERAL_FLUSH_RESPONSE_START/END in the legacy log, but two in the .NET7 log. Another observation, as I do not know whether this is contributing at all.

Comment: I'm not sure about your question. Because Response has no size limit. We can limit the response size by adding more parameter Content-Length in the response header.

Comment: I suggest you use your browser's developer tools and check the request and response headers to see if there's anything unusual. Pay special attention to whether the Content-Length in the response header is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem identified - I think!

The app is using the Telerik UI toolset. I am defining multiple DataSources using HTML Helpers. If I only define one DataSource in this way, the page gets served completely. Not quite the solution I wanted, but it will be manageable to redefine how I contextually apply different DataSource definitions to a common Grid definition.

In the process, I also updated the app to .NET 8. I don't know if this solution would "work" with .NET7.